# Error with nutch 1.11 : ....org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus.isDirectory()Z

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, web-crawler, nutch

I want to make an application in java like Google news.
For that I am doing that from scratch and doing basic setup with Nutch.

I am done with installation but getting error in one command.

Here is brief about tech. I am using

```
-nutch 1.11
-Cygwin
```

> - My first command was **:**

```
$ bin/nutch
```

which gives me perfect output.

> - Then I did URI crawling like **:**

```
$ bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls
```

Which created crawldb folder and crawl given url

> - Now I want to generate segments and which gives me given Error **:**

```
$ bin/nutch generate crawl/crawldb crawl/segments

Generator: starting at 2016-04-14 17:30:29
Generator: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
Generator: filtering: true
Generator: normalizing: true
Generator: Partitioning selected urls for politeness.
Generator: segment: crawl/segments/20160414173032
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus.isDirectory()Z
        at org.apache.nutch.util.LockUtil.removeLockFile(LockUtil.java:79)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Generator.generate(Generator.java:637)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Generator.run(Generator.java:743)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Generator.main(Generator.java:699)
```

I am not getting the problem. Is there mismatch between jars or having any other problem....

Answer (score 0):

Did you built nutch by yourself or used the packaged version?  I've just checkout the 1.11 branch of the Nutch repo and built it, executing your commands give the right output with no exception at all. Granted I've tested this on my local system (OS X) which is not windows/cygwin, but this shouldn't be a problem.

The 1.11 nutch branch is using hadoop 2.4.0, you can checkout which versions of hadoop are being pulled from the maven repo in the `runtime/local/lib/` folder, check the `hadoop-*` files.

Comment: I am using "hadoop-core-0.20.2" which is needed with nutch 1.11.
I tried with your given suggestion but it is not working...

Comment: If you're building nutch from the sources, try executing `ant clean` and then building with `ant` again. If you check the `ivy/ivy.xml` file you can see that all the `hadoop-` dependencies imported are of version `2.4.0`.

Comment: I am using packaged version. All other dependencies are of 2.4.0 version.. but need to add "hadoop-core-0.20.2"

Comment: Not sure why you need to add hadoop-core, couldn't find any reference to a hadoop-core dependency anywhere, actually the only mention in the `ivy.xml` file is to exclude `hadoop-core` from being fetched as a dependency of `webarchive-commons`, used on the WARC exporter.

Comment: There is no folder like "ivy" with nutch 1.11. This folder is there with new version of nutch like nutch 2.x... 

And if i am not providing that "hadoop-core-0.20.2" it gives me NullPointer exception with command " bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls "